# Different structs in one array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, struct

I have a struct called `trip`.

```
struct trip {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var elements: [Any] = []

    mutating func addItemToElements(newValue: Any) {
       elements.append(newValue)
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an array inside. I'm adding some other structs like `element_flight` into this array by function `addItemtoElements`.

```
struct element_flight {
    var origin: String
    var destination: String
    var flightno: String
    var departure: NSDate
    var arrival: NSDate
    var seat: String
}
```

Then I'm trying to create a list using table view:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "elementTrip", for: indexPath) as! CellInElementsOfTripsTableViewCell
    let elem = trips[0].elements[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainTextLabel.text = elem.origin //it doesn't work

    return cell
}
```

I can't get any of parts of struct (like `origin` in code). What am I doing wrong?

I'm creating similar structs to `element_flight` and it could be the best way to put it in one array and then show in table view.

Comment: `Try cast` them to the correct type OR store what type they are and cast them correctly to the concrete type. Right now, all the compiler knows is that `elem` is of type `Any` on line: `let elem = trips[0].elements[indexPath.row]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple, naive solution would be to cast `elem` to the correct type:

```
cell.mainTextLabel.text = (elem as! element_flight).origin
```

However, since the `elements` array can store `Any`, what if `elem` is some other type? Obviously, it will crash!

I don't understand why you want to store a bunch of `Any` in `elements`. This is a sign or bad code. `Any` is seldom used in Swift.

If you're just going to store *some* types, but not `Any` types, in `elements`, create a protocol and make all the types that you want to store conform to it. At least you get a little bit of type safety.

Let's say your array will only contain two structs: `element_flight` and `SomeOtherStruct`. You should do something like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol { // please give this a proper name yourself
    // properties/methods that are common among element_flight and SomOtherStruct
}

struct element_flight: SomeProtocol {
    // ...
}

struct SomeOtherStruct: SomeProtocol {
    // ...
}
```

And change the array to be of type `[SomeProtocol]`.

Now in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you need to test whether `elem` is `element_flight` or `SomeOtherStruct`:

```
if let flight = elem as? element_flight {
    cell.mainTextLabel.text = flight.origin
} else if let someOtherStuff = elem as? SomeOtherStruct {
    // do some other stuff
} else {
    // something's wrong if this is executed, maybe call fatalError
}
```

Comment: It was extremely helpful, now it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should cast them to `FlightInfo` (use this name instead of `element_flight` - type name in Swift should be written in CamelCase).

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
           cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "elementTrip", 
                     for: indexPath) as! CellInElementsOfTripsTableViewCell

  if let flightInfo = trips[0].elements[indexPath.row] as? FlightInfo {
    cell.mainTextLabel.text = flightInfo.origin //it doesn't work
  }

  return cell
}
```

Comment: Actually, `FlightInfo` is in _PascalCase_.

Answer (score 0):

A another approach would be to store the different structs in an `Any` array and use the `is` variable to test the type before copying it into a variable.